# How to format 1-liner for printing an object property

Tags: powershell

How can I write a quick 1-liner for write-host'ing an object property (let's say `Name`)?  Here is the object I want to print the `Name` of ...

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_ComputerSystem -namespace "root\CIMV2"
```

I tried ...

```
 write-host $_.name | Get-WmiObject -Class win32_ComputerSystem -namespace "root\CIMV2"
```

But this seems to still print all object properties.  What can I do to fix this command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter of the [`Select-Object` cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849895.aspx) to retrieve just the computer name, then pipe that to `Write-Host` (formatted as multiple lines for readability):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_ComputerSystem -namespace "root\CIMV2" `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name' `
    | Write-Host;
```

Alternatively, use the [`ForEach-Object` cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849731.aspx) to get the `Name` property:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_ComputerSystem -namespace "root\CIMV2" `
    | ForEach-Object { $_.Name; } `
    | Write-Host;
```

This is not a one-liner, but another approach similar to what you tried:

```
$computer = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_ComputerSystem -namespace "root\CIMV2";
Write-Host $computer.Name;
```

Note that since you only care about the `Name` property of `Win32_ComputerSystem`, it's a good idea to communicate that to `Get-WmiObject` using the `-Property` parameter so it doesn't bother returning information that will be discarded anyways:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_ComputerSystem -namespace "root\CIMV2" -Property 'Name'
```

Comment: Is the final `Write-Host` even necessary in your first two answers?  Btw thank you for thoroughly answering my question.

Comment: If you're just running those commands interactively in a console, then you can omit `Write-Host` and the computer name will still be printed to the console.  Without `Write-Host`, the command output will be passed to the next command (if this is running in a function or script); if there is no next command then, by default, it is written to the console.  Use `Write-Host` to explicitly direct PowerShell to write to the console.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer from BACON, another option is this (needs PowerShell v3 or higher):

```
Write-Host (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_ComputerSystem -namespace "root\CIMV2").Name
```

Comment: Ahhh, yes.  I didn't think to turn my third code snippet into a one-liner like this.  This works on PowerShell v2, by the way.

Comment: Hmm . . I thought that was an addition to v3. Although on reflection, I guess since it only returns one object, it would be fine in v2. I think that using this syntax to select a property from an array was added in v3.